# Why does React conditional rendering render NaN?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given `value = NaN`
When `value && value > 0 && <Component>`.

For some reason, the app renders "NaN" rather than not rendering anything. Am I missing something? I would have thought that because NaN is not greater than 0...it would not render anything?

Comment: did you check if value > 0 returns true if value = NaN? Since it seems your if statement returns true if it renders NaN

Comment: `NaN` is considered truthy so when `NaN > 0` fails the chained `&&` will just "return" the last truthy part of it.

Comment: @apokryfos where did you find that NaN is truthy? here states the opposite: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: @MarioVernari No you're right I misspoke. The failed `&&` will return the value it failed with. That seems to be in that link as well

Answer (score 3):

The [logical AND (`&&`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) expression syntax is:

```
expr1 && expr2
```

According to the documentation:

> If `expr1` can be converted to `true`, returns `expr2`; else, returns `expr1`.

Because `NaN` is `expr1` and is falsy, `NaN` is returned.

If you want the component to render only if `value` exists and is a number greater than 0, you may be able to simply write:

```
value > 0 && <Component>
```

Comment: Sidenote: The [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) seem to say that only `null` and `false` values do not produce any rendered output. I guess `undefined` might work as well but other falsy values are rendered

Answer (score 0):

so you basically might give this a shot

```
if value !== NaN {
    if value && value > 0 && <Component> {
       // do something 
    } else {}
} else {}
```

or chain the entire logic, but personally I'd prefer this for readability